# convert the string in servelt to json data and pass it to javascript : ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

I need to submit a form in ajax manner. when form submits convert the string inside the servlet to json data  and pass it to the javascript function and display these errors separately near to the error div tag below each input field.

```
  if(firstparamtr-condition)
    {
        String firsterror = "Error first";

        response.setContentType("application/json");

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");         

        response.getWriter().write(firsterror);       

    }

   if(secondparamtr-condition)
    {
        String seconderror = "Error second";

        response.setContentType("application/json");

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");         

        response.getWriter().write(seconderror);       

    }
```

javascript code

```
 posting.done(function( responseText ) {

   alert(responseText);

//HERE I need to separate the responseText and show that errors in the div tags named 'firstEr' and 'secondEr'      

      });
```

Comment: are you using any library? I would say the easiest is GSON from google.

Answer (score 0):

For converting String to JSON I use the [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) convertor, an example below:

`String string = "example"; // The String which you wish to convert
JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(string, JsonObject.class);`

Comment: how can I pass this convertedObject as response and alert them under javascript function

Comment: The same way you are setting the Headers, Content Type etc. you can also set the JSON as the Body of the response, such as: response.setBody(convertedObject)